# Is ginger drying out the same process as when making ground ginger?

Tags: ginger

If you Leave fresh ginger out it ‘goes bad’(looses its zingy flavour and becomes tough and chewy).

Some recipes call for dried ginger which I believe is achieved by heating in an oven or just leaving it out in the sun.

Is the process to get dried ginger doing the same thing as when ginger ‘goes bad’ from leaving it out so you don’t have to heat it or put it in the sun you could just leave it out?
Put another way is what I have described as ‘bad ginger’ usable to make dried ginger or is this not suitable?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drying any food is a race, if you do it too slowly it spoils or grows things. In hot and dry climates you can leave it out in the sun, in your kitchen it will just rot. You would need to use an oven or a dehydrator, otherwise it's just bad ginger.